# Ember data store handling array of objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember and exploring its capabilities by building a small module. I came across a scenario where I need to update the ember model content synchronously. The ember-data model contains an array of objects as contents.

I was hoping to perform a few tasks as follows

- Perform an array content reorder - for the sake of simplicity we
  can assume swapping the first and last item.
- Append a record
  without a network call
- Delete a record without a network call.

Doing these should automatically sync the data bindings/computed props

My data model after a peekAll call contains 10 records(shown below) on which I need to perform the above operations.

My model is as shown below

```
export default Model.extend({
  testId: attr('number'),
  name: attr('string')
});
```

[image]

What is the right approach to update the content record? Could someone please suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like the results of running something like `let arr = await store.findAll('test-model')`, is that correct? This is probably a [PromiseArray](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/PromiseArray) and you can access the data as a Javascript Array by calling `arr.slice()` on it. This will let you do normal array operations, though performing a content re-order doesn't really make much sense in this scenario. I assume you were using it as an example.

For adding and removing records without a network call you can do that by going back to the store and this is [what is covered in the docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/), you don't need to act on this Object you're looking at.

Adding a new record:

```js
let testModel = store.createRecord('test-model', {
  name: 'Lorem ipsum'
});

testModel.save(); //until you do this no network data will be sent
```

Removing a record:

```js
let testModel = store.peekRecord('testModel', 1); //to get a record with ID of 1
testModel.deleteRecord();
testModel.save(); //until you run save no network is sent
```

Once you've taken action like this on the store the data structure you posted above *may* be updated to contain the new data depending on how you accessed it originally. You can also re-fetch data from the store which will now know about your adding a deleting of models (even though you haven't saved it back to the server yet)

If you haven't saved yet and you re-do a `peekRecord` you'll need to filter out any deleted records from the results.

```
let undeletedModels = this.store.peekAll('test-model').filter(m => !m.isDeleted);
```

Comment: Thanks, @jrohnson. I already tried to delete the record as mentioned above, but the problem I'm facing is, even after deleting an entry, it is showing up the next time I'm doing a peekAll() call.

Comment: I've added some information on filtering out the deleted models when you use peekAll.

Comment: I tried using unloadRecord(testModel) instead of deleteRecord() and it seems to work as intended